# How can I add form fields when I click on link only by using Struts2 without javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

How can I add form fields when I click on link only by using Struts2, jsp without javascript/jquery.
I want when I click on addCompte link in the same page jsp add more fields about compte in addition of client fields already exist.

I want to stay in the same jsp page, when user click on the link more fields about Account display. the Question is when user click on the link which expression should me use in

This my client.jsp code:

```
<body>
<h1>Show de Clients</h1>

<s:form action="updateClient"> 
<s:textfield name="nom" label="Nom"/>
<s:textfield name="prenom" label="Prenom"/>
<s:textfield name="age" label="Age"/>
<s:textfield name="codeClient" label="CodeClient"/>

<s:url var="addCompteURL" action="addCompteToClient">
    <s:param name="codeClient" value="%{codeClient}"></s:param>
    <s:hidden name="moreCompte" value="yes" label="hide"></s:hidden>
</s:url> <s:a href="%{addCompteURL}" onclick="">addCompte</s:a>

<s:if test="%{moreCompte!=null}">
    <s:textfield name="numeroCompte" label="NumeroCompte"/>
    <s:textfield name="solde" label="Solde"/>
    <s:textfield name="dateCreation" label="DateCreation"/>
            <s:submit  action="addCompteToClient"
                value="addCompteToClient"       align="center">
        </s:submit>
        </s:if>

        <s:else>
        <s:submit action="updateClient" value="update client"
                        align="center">
        </s:submit>
        </s:else>

</s:form> 
</body>
```

this my action code ClientAction.java:

```
public class ClientAction extends ActionSupport{
private int codeClient;
private String nom;
private String prenom;
private int age;
private String adresse;
private String numeroCompte;
private double solde;
private Date dateCreation;
private Client client;
List<Client> clientList;
ServiceMetier serviceMetier= new ServiceMetierImpl();


public int getCodeClient() {
    return codeClient;
}
public void setCodeClient(int codeClient) {
    this.codeClient = codeClient;
}

public String getNom() {
    return nom;
}
public void setNom(String nom) {
    this.nom = nom;
}
public String getPrenom() {
    return prenom;
}
public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
    this.prenom = prenom;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
public String getAdresse() {
    return adresse;
}
public void setAdresse(String adresse) {
    this.adresse = adresse;
}

public String getNumeroCompte() {
    return numeroCompte;
}
public void setNumeroCompte(String numeroCompte) {
    this.numeroCompte = numeroCompte;
}
public double getSolde() {
    return solde;
}
public void setSolde(double solde) {
    this.solde = solde;
}
public Date getDateCreation() {
    return dateCreation;
}
public void setDateCreation(Date dateCreation) {
    this.dateCreation = dateCreation;
}

public Client getClient() {
    return client;
}
public void setClient(Client client) {
    this.client = client;
}
public List<Client> getClientList() {
    System.out.println("methode getClienList");
    return clientList;
}
public void setClientList(List<Client> clientList) {
    System.out.println("methode setClientList");
    this.clientList = clientList;
}
public String init(){
//      clientList = serviceMetier.getAllClient();
    System.out.println("methode init ");
    return SUCCESS;
}
public String afficher(){
    clientList=serviceMetier.getAllClient();
//      client=serviceMetier.getClient(9);
    System.out.println("methode afficher "+clientList);
    return SUCCESS;
}
public String ajouter(){
    System.out.println("methode afficher "+clientList);
    BanqueFactory banque=new BanqueFactory();
    Compte compte=banque.buildCompte();
    compte.setNumeroCompte(numeroCompte);
    compte.setSolde(solde);
    compte.setDateCreation(dateCreation);
    Client client=banque.buildClient();
    client.setCodeClient(codeClient);
    client.setNom(nom);
    client.setPrenom(prenom);
    client.setAge(age);
    client.setAdresse(adresse);
    client.addCompte(compte);
    serviceMetier.createClient(client);
    clientList=serviceMetier.getAllClient();

    return SUCCESS;
}
public String addCompte(){
    System.out.println("methode addCompte");
    /*
    BanqueFactory banque=new BanqueFactory();
    Compte compte=banque.buildCompte();
    compte.setNumeroCompte(numeroCompte);
    compte.setSolde(solde);
    compte.setDateCreation(dateCreation);
    Client client=banque.buildClient();
    client.setCodeClient(codeClient);
    client.setNom(nom);
    client.setPrenom(prenom);
    client.setAge(age);
    client.setAdresse(adresse);
    client.addCompte(compte);
    serviceMetier.updateClient(client);
//      if(codeClient>0){
//      serviceMetier.updateClient(codeClient);
//      codeClient=0;
//      }

 */
    client=serviceMetier.getClient(codeClient);

    return SUCCESS;
}
public String update(){
    client=serviceMetier.getClient(codeClient);
    if(nom!=null){
        client.setNom(nom);
    }
    if(prenom!=null){
        client.setPrenom(prenom);
    }
    if(age!=0){
        client.setAge(age);
    }
    if(adresse!=null){
        client.setAdresse(adresse);
    }
    serviceMetier.updateClient(client);
    return SUCCESS;
}
public String delete(){
    System.out.println("methode delete");
//      if(codeClient>0){
    serviceMetier.deleteClient(codeClient);
//      codeClient=0;
//      }
    clientList=serviceMetier.getAllClient();
    return SUCCESS;
}


}
```

this my struts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources" />
<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
    <action name= "login" class="org.presentation.action.Account">
    <result name="reussite" type="redirectAction">listClient</result>
    <result name="echec">logging.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="clientInit" class="org.presentation.action.ClientAction"
        method="init">
        <result name="success">index.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name= "addClient" class="org.presentation.action.ClientAction"
    method="ajouter">
    <result name="success">clientShow.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="listClient" class="org.presentation.action.ClientAction"
        method="afficher">
        <result name="success">clientShow.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="updateClient" class="org.presentation.action.ClientAction"
        method="update">
        <result name="success">client.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="addCompteToClient"   class="org.presentation.action.ClientAction"
        method="addCompte">
        <result name="success">client.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="deleteClient" class="org.presentation.action.ClientAction"
        method="delete">
        <result name="success">clientShow.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>  
</struts>
```

It's possible by using Struts2, jsp without javascript/jquery? if not how can I add jquery code in Struts2?

Comment: W/o js -> submit form and add new instance of your object to list, use iterator in jsp to show objects from that list. *How to add jQuery code to S2* -> like to any other page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Struts2 - Dynamic form fields and database data retrieval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705413/struts2-dynamic-form-fields-and-database-data-retrieval)

Comment: Unless you want to have a complete redirect and do something on the server side to indicate the page should have more fields, you can't. And I'd say you *shouldn't*, 'cuz that'd be a pretty yucky UX.

Comment: I want to stay in the same jsp page, when user click on the link more fields about Account display. the Question is when user click on the link which expression should me use in <s:if test="expression" to verify if the user click on the link or not.